# Sharepoint Error during decryption

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want programmatically use the powershell add server to sharepoint 2010 farm. So. When I do with Products Configuration Wizard, It's successfully added to farm. But when I do this way (on powershell),program throw exception.

```
PS C:\Users\SPAdmin> $securePassPhrase =(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@$$w0r
d" -AsPlaintext -Force)
PS C:\Users\SPAdmin> Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName "SharepointCo
nfig" -DatabaseServer "AD\MSSQLSERVER" -PassPhrase $securePassPhrase

Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase : Error during decryption. Ensure the passphrase is correct.
At line:1 char:32
+ Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase <<<<  -DatabaseName "SharepointConfig" -Data
baseServer "AD\MSSQLSERVER" -PassPhrase $securePassPhrase
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:
SPCmdletConnectSPConfigurationDatabase) [Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase],
ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletConnectS
PConfigurationDatabase
```

So how it's fix?

Answer (score 0):

Resolution

There are a couple of things to have in place, as the error is saying “SharePoint unable to Decrypt the passphrase”.

```
Make sure farm admin account has DBO rights on the Configuration Database,
Make sure you login with farm admin. If any other account ( i.e. install account) then that account should also have DBO on Config Database.
Clear the Configuration Cache on the SharePoint Servers (all servers in the farm).
    If you want to do manually follow this: Clearing the Configuration Cache for SharePoint Jump
    Or you can use the script from here: Clear Configuration Cache Jump
```

Once you are done with above then run the Config Wizard again, Prefer to run as PSConfig first.
psconfig.exe -cmd configdb -connect -server "KFSQL.krossfarm.com" -database KF-Configdb -passphrase "SP@016farm" -localserverrole​ "Custom"

Once this completes successfully, then run the SharePoint Product and Technology Configuration wizard via GUI.